# Return value based on earliest date value within set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula to return the value from Column E, based on the earliest date in column B, within the Values in Column A in Sample table I attached.

### I this instance, I seek to return 50% for Company A, 75% for Company B, and 50% for Company C.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j79RM.png)

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sample data is located at `A1:E7` *(adjust formulas as required)*

*(Enter the* `FormulaArray` *pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see `{` `}` around the formula if entered correctly)*

- To list Companies enter this `FormulaArray` in G2` and copy till last record

  ```
  =IFERROR( INDEX( $A$1:$A$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( $G$1:$G1, $A$1:$A$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
  ```
- To extract the earliest `% Passed` for each company enter this `FormulaArray` in `H2` and copy till last record

  ```
  =IF( EXACT( $G2, "" ), "",
  INDEX( $E$1:$E$7,
  MATCH( SMALL( IFERROR( $B$1:$B$7 * ( $A$1:$A$7 = $G2 ) * 1, 0 ),
  1 + COUNTIF( $A$1:$A$7, "<>" & $G2 ) ),
  $B$1:$B$7 * ( $A$1:$A$7 = $G2 ) * 1, 0 ) ) )
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I'm just getting a chance to get back to this now - I'll follow up when I get it to work

Comment: Let me know if you have any question, also if it works please acknowledge the answer.

Comment: This was fantastic - it worked for exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the percentage for when column A has a value of "A":

```
=MAX((MIN(IF(B2:B99*(A2:A99="a"),B2:B99))=B2:B99)*E2:E99)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: if your data extend further down than row 99, then increase the 99s in the formula.

Note: you can edit the `"a"` in the center of the formula for `"b"` or `"c"`. Better still would be a reference to a cell containing the value to calculate on. For example, let's say you enter `A` in cell G1, you could do this:

```
=MAX((MIN(IF(B2:B99*(A2:A99=G1),B2:B99))=B2:B99)*E2:E99)
```

Comment: @guest_accnt Were you able to get this going?

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I'm just getting a chance to get back to this now - I'll follow up when I get it to work